# Assign RegEx submatches to variables or map (C++/C)

Tags: c++, c, regex

I need to extract the *same* type of information (e.g. First name, Last Name, Telephone, ...), from numerous different text sources, each with a different format & different order of the variables of interest.

I want a function that does the extraction based on a regular expression and returns the result as *descriptive* variables.  In other words, instead of returning each match result as `submatch[0], submatch[1], submatch[2], ...,` have it do either of the following:

1. return `std::map` so that the submatches can be accessed via:

   `submatch["first_name"], submatch["last_name"], submatch["telephone"]`
2. return a variables with the submatches so that the submatches can be accessed via:

   `submatch_first_name, submatch_last_name, submatch_telephone`

I can write a wrapper class around `boost::regex` to do the first one, but I was hoping there would be a built-in or a more elegant way to do this in C++/Boost/STL/C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use "named capture groups"?  It seems like returning a map is exactly what you want.

For example, in [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/source/browse/re2/re2.h#414)

Check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) see if your favorite regex library supports named captures.

Comment: Thank you -- "named capture groups" is exactly what I want.  I was using Boost::regex but I think a switch to Boost::xpressive will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use enumerations or integral constants to get named indices, e.g.:

```
enum NamedIndices {
    FirstName = 0,
    LastName  = 1,
    // ...
};

// ...
std::string first = submatch[FirstName];
std::string last  = submatch[LastName ];
```

Comment: Thank you for fast response.

I considered enum's but the problem is the order changes.  I.e. for one regex, submatch[0] is the "First Name", for another regex, submatch[0] is the telephone.

Comment: @Michael: Can't you provide a mapping *(InputSource,ResultEnumerator) -> SubmatchIndex* then?

Answer (score 1):

Boost::Regex also has built-in support for named capture groups via the following syntax

```
(?<name>.*)
```

with the regular expression added after the name e.g.

```
const boost::wregex dateTimeRegex(L"(?<year>[[:d:]]{4})\\.(?<month>[[:d:]]{2})\\.(?<day>[[:d:]]{2}) (?<hr>[[:d:]]{2}):(?<min>[[:d:]]{2}):(?<sec>[[:d:]]{2})");
boost::wsmatch result;
if(boost::regex_match(currentLine, result, dateTimeRegex))
{
    if(result[0].matched)
    {
        const int year = boost::lexical_cast<int>(result.str(L"year"));
        const int month = boost::lexical_cast<int>(result.str(L"month"));
        //...
    }
}
```